# Should one use an IIFE or object properties to creatic static variables?

Tags: javascript

Sometimes when I need a static variable I use and immediately invoked function expression (IIFE) - example1.

```
(function(){
    var private_statik = 'hi',
        publik = {};
    return publik;
}())
```

other times I just tack them on as properties to the function which needs them as such - example2.

```
function foo () {
}
foo.statik = 'hello';
```

Example1 is good b.c. I get the benefit of encapsulation ( privacy ).  Example 2 is good b.c. it is simple and there is no overhead for the self-execution.

Are there any other things to consider?

The case specific I have is a page changer - `sFlipPage()`.  I want to cache all the DOM elements in a static location so they are available on each call and I don't have to pull them from the DOM each time I call the function.

Thanks!

Comment: Bookmarks mean other people want to hear the answer too

Comment: How can a variable be static when used in an IIFE? Isn't it inherently tied to the particular IIFE itself?

Comment: That's what private means, it is only available inside the IIFE.  Static means that it persists after the function has completed running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The primary difference is privacy and execution order.  With an IIFE you can make your static variables private.  With a plain function you can not.  In order to encourage good OO design ( encapsulation ) I would suggest using an IIFE by default.

The trade-off is that an IIFE is invoked immediately not just when you need that particular object.